# Flutter: How to call Apple pay bottom sheet in in_app_purchase?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I tried to implement subscriptions in our app, and i stop on official [flutter in_app_purchase plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase), i tried to use their example code, and it seems to work, it loads the products and prices for them from AppleConnect, but when I try to buy a subscription, I get this dialog box([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4IDo.png)), instead of this([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbY01.png)).

Q: How can I call Apple pay bottom sheet like on second image when purchasing a subscription?

Comment: Maybe because you are in environnement Sandbox

Comment: @Vanilil i tried to upload release version to TestFlight, and nothing happened, still this dialog box.

Comment: You are confusing two different payment processes. The first dialog is what you expect to see for an in-app purchase. The second view is for an Apple Pay purchase. IAP and Apple Pay are different things. Apple Pay is for purchasing physical goods and real world services (Like a pizza or an oil change). You won't see the Apple Pay sheet when purchasing a subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as your app is in the SandBox Environment you will just get the Dialog box like this ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4IDo.png)) even in the test flight you will get the same dialog because it still considered as a Sandbox Environment.

After your app is live on the App store you will see the similar bottom sheet like this ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbY01.png)) not exactly same as this is a Apple Pay sheet. but some what similar to this.

Comment: Oh, okay. I will check that on next release version, and if everything will okay - i will check this answer as correct. Thank you!